# Application of linear transformation and matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, big-list

I have been studying linear algebra for some time now, and I have seen some really interesting applications of linear transformation and matrices such as finding the integral $\int x^2e^x dx$. Does anyone have some other interesting or unexpected uses of linear algebra in analysis or any other field of mathematics?

Comment: A few examples: a lot of graph theory uses linear algebra, representation theory is a linear-algebraic approach to abstract algebra, quantum mechanics uses linear algebra heavily, the study of differential equations and partial differential equations leans heavily on linear algebra

Comment: Could you tell us more about this trick for finding that integral?

Comment: If you define a basis B as $B=(e^x, x e^x ,x^2 e^x)$, and you write and define $D:B \rightarrow B$, where D is a differential operator, then you can find a matrix for that transformation, and inverse of that matrix represents integration.

Comment: Oh, that's nifty

Comment: I know right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One impressive example is the application of linear algebra to the study of [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), which is a combination of probability and graph theory. In a nutshell, a Markov chain is a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) on which we "hop" between vertices.  At any given moment, the probability of hopping from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ is given by a (constant) probability $p_{i,j}$.

As it turns out, the "probability-matrix" $P$ whose $i,j$ entries are $p_{ij}$ encapsulates the behavior of a Markov chain very well.  In particular, it turns out that the $i,j$ entry of $P^k$ is the probability that, in $k$ steps, we transition from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

An important result is that for a Markov chain (satisfying certain assumptions) with probability matrix $P$, the [stationary distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution) of the Markov chain can be computed as the eigenvector of $P^T$ corresponding to $\lambda = 1$. As it so happens, it is precisely this trick which is the main idea behind the [PageRank algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) (Google's first search algorithm, which is a big part of how the company became successful).

Comment: That sounds really interesting, I will take a look, thanks.